# how to combine exponents? (x**a)**b => x**(a*b)?

Tags: python, simplify, sympy, exponent

how to simplify exponents in equations in sympy

```
from sympy import symbols 
a,b,c,d,e,f=symbols('abcdef')
j=(a**b**5)**(b**10)
print j 
(a**(b**5))**(b**10) #ans even after using expand simplify 
# desired output 
a**(b**15)
```

and if  it is not possible with sympy which module should i import in python?

**edit**
even if i  define 'b' as real,and also all other symbols

b=symbols('b',real=True)
not getting simplified exponents
it simplifies only if exponents are  constants

```
a=symbols('a',real=True)
b=symbols('b',real=True)
(a**5)**10
 a**50  #simplifies only if exp are numbers
(a**b**5)**b**10


(a**(b**5))**b**10  #no simplification
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(x<sup>m</sup>)<sup>n</sup> = x<sup>mn</sup> is true [only if m, n are real](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponent#Failure_of_power_and_logarithm_identities).

```
>>> import math
>>> x = math.e
>>> m = 2j*math.pi
>>> (x**m)**m      # (e^(2πi))^(2πi) = 1^(2πi) = 1
(1.0000000000000016+0j)
>>> x**(m*m)       # e^(2πi×2πi) = e^(-4π²) ≠ 1
(7.157165835186074e-18-0j)
```

AFAIK, [sympy supports complex numbers](http://code.google.com/p/sympy/#Features), so I believe this simplification should not be done unless you can prove `b` is real.

---

Edit: It is also false if x is not positive.

```
>>> x = -2
>>> m = 2
>>> n = 0.5
>>> (x**m)**n
2.0
>>> x**(m*n)
-2.0
```

Edit(by gnibbler): Here is the original example with Kenny's restrictions applied

```
>>> from sympy import symbols 
>>> a,b=symbols('ab', real=True, positive=True)
>>> j=(a**b**5)**(b**10)
>>> print j
a**(b**15)
```

Comment: Good answer, but the output is the same for `a,b,c,d,e,f = symbols("abcdef", real=True)`

Comment: @gnib: Oops looks like I've missed another restriction (x > 0).

Comment: thanx!kenny and gnib ,it works if we define symbol;
a=symbols('a',real=True,positive=True)

Answer (score 2):

```
a,b,c=symbols('abc',real=True,positive=True)
(a**b**5)**b**10
a**(b**15)#ans
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/sympy/issues/detail?id=1565).